# Merging two already existing implementation under a common interface

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct InterfaceA
{
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

void specific_a( InterfaceA& i )
{
    i.a(); 
}

struct InterfaceB
{
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

void specific_b( InterfaceB& i )
{
    i.b(); 
}

struct CommonInterface : InterfaceA, InterfaceB 
{
    
};

void common( CommonInterface& i )
{
    i.a();
    i.b();
    specific_a(i);
    specific_b(i);
}

struct A : InterfaceA
{
    void a()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : InterfaceB
{
    void b()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm B" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct Common : CommonInterface, private A, private B
{
    using A::a; // this does not work
    using B::b; // this does not work
};
 
int main()
{
    Common c;
    common(c);
}
```

Without having to manually redirect every method in `InterfaceA` and in `InterfaceB` to their concrete types?

Comment: you mean without `using A::a; using B::b;` ?

Comment: those do not actually work

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Do you just want to define two overloads of a single `specific` function?

Comment: Try virtual inheritance...

Comment: And you should add virtual destructors!

Comment: If compile time reflection ever comes to C++, it may be possible to have a library implementation mimicking interface intersection that some other languages have as a language feature. Imagine taking as parameter something like `intersection_of<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>`, without boiler-plate. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah that would be pretty much awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

With [virtual inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes):

```
struct CommonInterface : virtual InterfaceA, virtual InterfaceB 
{};

struct A : virtual InterfaceA
{
    void a() override { std::cout << "I'm A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : virtual InterfaceB
{
    void b() override { std::cout << "I'm B" << std::endl; }
};

struct Common : CommonInterface, private A, private B
{
    using A::a;
    using B::b;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b796dc90436ef8ff)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The downside is that unless you can change all of those classes to use virtual inheritance, you're out of luck.